# Canon Rebel T3 wont take the picture I want

Tags: zoom

I'm new to the camera and photography so I am sorry in advance...

With both lenses the camera came with (18-55 and 75-300) if I use the camera's magnifier or the lenses zoom for close up pics from near or far, the camera will take a picture from further away than what is shown on the screen.  Why?

Shouldn't it take whatever picture is shown on the screen?

Thx

Looking for beginner classes now...

Comment: Looks like you will find your answer in this previous question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39521/why-dont-the-zoom-buttons-work-on-my-dslr

Comment: I think Danny is likely right. _Does_ that answer your question? I think it might, but you do specifically say that the lens's zoom doesn't work either. Can you describe a little more clearly exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now to manually focus on the lense and crop the picture later.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the Live View and **look through the viewfinder** instead. What you see in the viewfinder is what the sensor will see. That's largely true for Live View mode too, but Live View lets you magnify a part of the image (mainly so that you can check focus); the camera will still record the whole image, not just the magnified part, when you take the picture.

Answer (score 1):

DSLRs use optical zoom, not digital.  Digital zoom is simply a crop of the full size image that the sensor picks up.  You can take a photo and crop it after the fact and it will be the same exact quality as what you would get if you could only take a picture of what you have magnified.

Since DSLRs are designed to use optical lenses for their zooming, they do not support digital zoom generally.